# Dir wildcard and comma

Tags: cmd

I was working on a Dir command, and I noticed this odd behavior that I can't seem to explain:

```
dir *SQHSER-1.0* /B /S |findstr  /v "\Archive" |findstr "pdf" |findstr /v "Awaiting"
```

This works properly and only returns the a pdf file whose name contains the string SQHSER-1.0 not in archive or awaiting folders
Meanwhile,

```
dir *SQHSER-1.0,* /B /S |findstr  /v "\Archive" |findstr "pdf" |findstr /v "Awaiting"
```

Returns every single PDF in the subdirectories. Is this a bug or am I missing something there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir "*SQHSER-1.0,*" /B /S |findstr  /v "\Archive" |findstr "pdf" |findstr /v "Awaiting"
```

should fix your problem - quoting file/pathnames is normally the solution to problems with ambiguous separators.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is seen as a separator (just as a space would be).  So you're asking `dir` to return files that end with `SQHSER-1.0` and then "all files".  Which, of course, results in getting all files.

What were you hoping to do with the comma?

Comment: The comma was part of a tag used for searching the file. I didn't realize it was equivalent to a space. Thanks!